# JPA EntityManager find method doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa

I want to write a method which gets me back the `customerId` via the `cardId`, but this isn't working, Eclipse says `customerId` cant be resolved to a variable

```
    public CustomerMapping getCustomerMapping(String cardId) {

            this.getEntityManager();
            return em.find(CustomerMapping.class, customerId);
    }




@Stateless
public class CustomerMappingEJB {

    private EntityManager em;


    private void getEntityManager() {
        em = MultiTenantEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();
    }

    private void beginTransaction() {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    private void commitTransaction() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }


    private void insert(CustomerMapping customerMapping) {
        em.persist(customerMapping);
    }

    public CustomerMapping getCustomerMapping(long id) {

        this.getEntityManager();
        return em.find(CustomerMapping.class, id);
    }

    public List<CustomerMapping> getCustomerMappings() {

        TypedQuery<CustomerMapping> query = null;

            this.getEntityManager();
            query = em.createNamedQuery("AllCustomerIds", CustomerMapping.class);       

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public CustomerMappingHelper getCustomerMappingHelper(String cardId) {

        this.getEntityManager();
        return em.find(CustomerMappingHelper.class, cardId);
    }

    public CustomerMapping addNew(CustomerMapping customerMapping) {
        this.getEntityManager();
        this.beginTransaction();
        this.insert(customerMapping);
        this.commitTransaction();
        return customerMapping;
    }
}
```

I didn't put the `MultiTenantEntityManagerFactory` class in here, since I guess you won't need that, then I have the `CustomerMapping` class with the "bunch of list" as you called it and there are just some set and get methods for id,cardId and customerId i didnt copy that in also since this will be very big if you want that too I will do

```
public class CustomerMapping {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Basic
    private String customerId;

    @Basic
    private String cardId;

    @Basic
    private String hashKey;

}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `customerId` inside that method and `customerId` is not passed in as a parameter, it's not declared as a variable, so you get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `CustomerMapping` by `cardId` using `JPQL`. A more optimal solution will be to use projections.

```
public String getCustomerMappingCustomerId(String cardId) {
    getEntityManager();        
    CustomerMapping result = first(em.createQuery(
        "select c from CustomerMapping c where c.cardId = :cardId")
        .setParameter("cardId", cardId).getResultList());
    return result ==  null ? null : result.getCustomerId(); 
}

private static <T> T first(List<T> items) {
    return items == null || items.isEmpty() ? null : items.get(0);
}
```

Comment: what you wrote is completely not for what I was asking for my customerId is a String not a Long, secondly where is the operation in that code where you find that customerId through a cardId ?

Comment: @ECasio I am not a telepath :) Please, add your entities to the question. Hurry up, cause closing ;)

Comment: @ECasio, You are willing to find customerId from cardId right? If so, then you will get an instance of type CustomerMapping from find method.Later get the customerId from that same instance.

Comment: @VSK yes you understood what I want but still I didn't get how to implement that, I get an intance of type CustomerMapping and later I will use a get method to get the cardId from that instance is that right?

Comment: @ECasio I update. You should add the full mapping, not a strange bunch of fields.

Comment: @v.ladynevthanks buddy :) have a nice rest day =)

Comment: @ECasio You too. Thanks for accepting. :)